# Spark-submit master url and SparkSession master url in the main class, what is difference?

Tags: apache-spark

When submitting a job with spark-submit I set the master URL and give him a main class, ex:

`spark-submit --class WordCount --master spark://spark:7077 my.jar`

But inside this main class my spark context define another master url :

```
SparkSession.builder().appName("Word2vec").master("local").
```

This get me confused, what happens if I send a job with `spark-submit` to the master of a standalone cluster (`spark://spark:7077`) that start a `SparkSession` with a `local` master ?

Should the `SparkSession` master url always be the same as the `spark-submit` url when executed on a cluster ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between these properties. If set both, properties set directly in application take precedence. To quote [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application and merged with those specified through SparkConf. Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I missed this part of the documentation